# Execute generic AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, generics, android-asynctask

I'm trying to write a static utility function that executes generic AsyncTasks.
I came up with this:

```
public static void executeAsync(Class<? extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>> task, Object[] params) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    } else {
        task.execute(params);
    }
}
```

But it's not good enough to even compile.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just:

```
public static void executeAsync(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task, Object[] params) {
```

instead of:

```
public static void executeAsync(Class<? extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>> task, // ...
```

as you do not need to pass the class but the actual instance.

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in comment there was also a parametrized type mismatch, so you also need to adjust the parameter type. So the signature should look like:

```
public static void executeAsync(AsyncTask<Object, ?, ?> task, Object[] params)
```

Or (in order to make it more "flexible")

```
public static <T> void executeAsync(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task, T... params) {
```

A supress lint annotation `@SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi" })` can also be expected if you have lint enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Had to change the ?'s to Objects, so please update..
public static void executeAsync(AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> task, Object[] params)

Comment: You are right. In fact it suffices to be `executeAsync(AsyncTask<Object, ?, ?> task, Object[] params)` - only the first parametrized type is relevant.

Comment: Having trouble calling the function..
GetGoogleProfileTask task = new GetGoogleProfileTask(data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME));
executeAsync(task, null);
gives a compile error

Comment: And how does `GetGoogleProfileTask` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Params is of type Object[], but ASyncTask is of type "any" (`<?>`). But array of generics is not supported by Java. So `?[] params` is not possible.

Maybe using `<? extends Object>` helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's simplier to use a Service, it can be launched multiple times